# How to combined plugin in nopcommerce?

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I' m using nopcommerce open source. I have two plugin for shipping.

```
shipping.ByTotal
shipping.ByWeight
```

Now I want to write one plugin using these two plugin.
because shipping cost depend both item total and item weight.
How can I do it? Do you have any idea about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add a Reference to these projects, and use their service to do the trick. For example, *Shopping.ByWeight* plugin has an *IShippingByWeightService*. Inject his interface into your plugin and you are good to go. :)